# map.js is not working with highstock in 4.2.4 version ( mapNavigation )

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to integrate **mapNavigation** future. MapNavigation is available on map.js.

I have seem some working example of map.js with highstock for mapNavigation.

```
mapNavigation = {
   enabled: true,
   enableButtons: false
}
```

My problem on 4.2.4 only. Latest version is working fine

Getting following error.

Cannot read property 'documentElement' of undefined

http://jsfiddle.net/MohaideenIsmail/uvmfkcvu/ - Working example with latest version ( 5.0.2 )

http://jsfiddle.net/MohaideenIsmail/uvmfkcvu/1/ - Not working in 4.2.4 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 4.2.4 version use all of script file of that version

[Forked Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvLv9to1/)

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/4.2.4/highstock.js">
</script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/4.2.4/modules/map.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/4.2.4/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```